# MATLAB: Error using symbol array in my system of ODEs

Tags: matlab, system, symbols, ode

```
syms L(t) [1 n];
syms M(t) [1 n];
syms massbal_tray [1 n];
massbal_tray(1) = diff(M(1),t) == L(2)-L(1);
```

I want to use the above code so I can create a system with n ODEs, but I need to treat the first equation differently. I plan to do the rest in a for loop. However I'm getting an error and can't isolate the problem:

> Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a
> different number of elements.
>
> Error in sym/privsubsasgn (line 1151)

> ```
>             L_tilde2 = builtin('subsasgn',L_tilde,struct('type','()','subs',{varargin}),R_tilde);
> ```
>
> Error in sym/subsasgn (line 972)

> ```
>         C = privsubsasgn(L,R,inds{:});
> ```
>
> Error in msche_dist (line 28)
>
> ```
> massbal_tray(1) = diff(M(1),t) ==
> > L(2)-L(1);
> ```